# How to achieve QR code with both url and content

Tags: java, qr-code

In my application, I am embedding content to a QR code and when I read it with my mobile application, I am parsing it and do a request to the server with parsed information.

However, I want to redirect users to a certain webpage where they can download my mobile application if they don't scan it with it. As far as I know, I can do this with "tag" or some other keyword feature of the QR code. However, I am a student, I don't have money to put my application to the play store. It is an optional task for my homework (in fact, it is not a task, it just looks good in this way) and I need this feature to improve the usability of my project.

So, once again, if the user has my app, he will scan the QR code, my code will fetch the necessary information from the QR and do a request to my server. This part is already done. If he does not have my app, I want to redirect him to a certain web page where he can download my APK file. I have prepared a webpage for that purpose. The scanned thing should open a browser, then the user manually downloads the APK and installs it.

Hopefully, I am clear. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO this is a design question about the data stored in your QR code.

At a very basic level, a QR code only contains text data. It is up to the scanner application to interpret the meaning of the decoded text, and do something with it.

If you are storing a meaningless string, such as "MYAPP-1234", your app would be able to interpret that string and make a call to yourserver/yourapi/1234, but any QR code reader would show the raw text and nothing else.

To achieve your goal, your QR code contents must be standard enough so that any QR code scanner application would be able to redirect the user to your server. If you are storing "https://yourserver/qrcode/1234", that's where the user with a random QR code scanner will land. Your server can then issue a 302 redirect to your app's download page.

If this very same QRCode is scanned from your app, you can implement the logic to strip out the start of the URL, retrieve the interresting bit (the 1234 ID in the example) and do the intended request to your server (ex : https://yourserver/yourapi/1234)